# ValidationException One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key primary_key in the item

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless to expose HTTP request in getwayapi, lambda function and dynamodb but got an error "ValidationException One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key primary_key in the item". Please help me!

Here my code in createCustomer.js file

```
'use strick'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const { tableName } = require('./config');

module.exports.createCustomer = async(event) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64').toString()))
    const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
    const putParams = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: {
            primary_key: body.name,
            email: body.email
        }
    }
    await dynamoDb.put(putParams).promise()

    return {
        statusCode: 201
    }
}
```

and here is my serverless.yml file code

```
org: surangi
app: my-api
service: my-api
frameworkVersion: '3'


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_CUSTOMER_TABLE: ${self:service}-customerTable-${sls:stage}
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 'dynamodb:PutItem'
            - 'dynamodb:Get*'
            - 'dynamodb:Scan*'
            - 'dynamodb:UpdateItem'
            - 'dynamodb:DeleteItem'
          Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:table/${self:service}-customerTable-${sls:stage}

functions:
  createCustomer:
    handler: createCustomer.createCustomer
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: post

resources:
  Resources:
    CustomerTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: primary_key
            AttributeType: S
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: primary_key
            KeyType: HASH
        TableName: ${self:service}-customerTable-${sls:stage}
```

my .env file has this variable:
DYNAMODB_CUSTOMER_TABLE: "my-api-customerTable-dev"

now i am getting an error as:

node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js
52
resp.error = util.error(new Error(), error);
^ ValidationException One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key primary_key in the item

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a console.log statement to print out the value of variables. It looks to me as if the body is probably not being extracted correctly and so there is no value for the primary key. You can see the value of the variable you console.log in your logs in CloudWatch or in the Serverless Framework dashboard if you use it.

Comment: yeah you are correct. it doesnot print the values, it prints as undefine but problem is I could not solve that. If you can tell me how to fix it

Comment: @SurangiKanchana How do you invoke that function?